# How to make a static binary build of vorbis-tools ogg123?

Tags: make, configure, ogg, vorbis

In order to run `ogg123` (for getting wav from ogg vorbis) I need to get (not found) or compile static build. I tried this on Amazon Linux (the same version as current AWS Lambda):

```
./configure --disable-shared --enable-static
make LDFLAGS=-lm SHARED=0 CC='gcc -static'
```

Produced `ogg123` filesize is 288K but when I copied that file to another Amazon Linux and tried to run I get
`error while loading shared libraries: libvorbisfile.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: It looks like this wasn't static build. One comment, it might be better to also supply `-fPIC` gcc flag although that won't solve this particular problem. Can you post a link to the source code that you're trying to compile?

Comment: The source code of `ogg123` is here https://github.com/xiph/vorbis-tools/tree/master/ogg123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to decode `wav` from `ogg vorbis`, you can simply use `oggdec` utility to do that, instead of `ogg123` (which has more dependencies).

To build a "static" version of `oggdec`, you will first need to build static versions of `libogg` and `libvorbis` libraries, like this:

```
#Create staging directory
STAGING=$HOME/staging/vorbis-tools
mkdir -p $STAGING

#Sources
SRC=$STAGING/src
mkdir -p $SRC

#Build artifacts
OUT=$STAGING/build
mkdir -p $OUT

#Build a static version of "libogg"
wget downloads.xiph.org/releases/ogg/libogg-1.3.1.tar.xz -qO-|tar -C $SRC -xJ
pushd $SRC/libogg*/
./configure --prefix=$OUT --disable-shared
make install
popd

#Build a static version of "libvorbis"
wget http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/vorbis/libvorbis-1.3.5.tar.xz -qO-|tar -C $SRC -xJ
pushd $SRC/libvorbis*/
./configure --prefix=$OUT LDFLAGS="-L$OUT/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I$OUT/include" --disable-shared
make install
popd
```

Now you can build `oggdec` (vorbis-tools), statically linked to `libogg` and `libvorbis`:

```
#Build "vorbis-tools"
wget downloads.xiph.org/releases/vorbis/vorbis-tools-1.4.0.tar.gz -qO- | tar -C $SRC -xz
pushd $SRC/vorbis-tools*/
./configure LDFLAGS="-L$OUT/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I$OUT/include"
make
popd
```

You can use [ldd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), to
check the list of dependencies for your newly built `oggdec` binary:

```
ldd $SRC/vorbis-tools*/oggdec/oggdec

linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc85792000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbcba839000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbcba48e000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbcbab3a000)
```

The resulting binary is not really fully "static", as it still exposes dependency on some system libraries (in particular "libc" and "libm"), but that should be just fine for running it under "Amazon Linux".

Comment: Awesome advice, helped me out a lot statically linking a similar set of utilities!

Comment: Works for `oggenc`, thank you again.